# How do I sort by an attribute of another entity in Spring?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, sorting

so I'm working on a website (Angular frontend, Java backend).

I've got two different @Entity classes. They're connected as 1:1.
Let's call them `A` and `B`. `A` has attributes `a1`, `a2` and `b_id`, `B` has `b1`, `b2`.

Now I made an interface which extends `CrudRepository<A, Long>` where I join those two tables via JPQL.
The problem is now: whenever I want to order them by an attribute present in A it works and when I want to sort them by an attribute in B it says "can't find `b1` in `A`".

Example query:

```
@Query("SELECT ... FROM A a JOIN B b ON a.b.id = b.id")
Page<CustomTableRow> test(Pageable pageable);
```

Current pageable:

```
PageRequest.of(page, pageSize, Sort.by(direction, attributeName))
```

At first I thought Spring would automatically search for the attribute in one of the two classes but it seems it doesn't.
One workaround would be to set a prefix for the attributeName depending on where I expect them to be, meaning I have to switch-case my way through all attributes I have (like 20) and set either an "a." or "b." in front of the attributeName from the HTTP request, to get stuff like this:

`Sort.by(direction, "b.b2")` or `Sort.by(direction, "a.a2")` instead of, say, `Sort.by(direction, "b2")`, which would produce the error mentioned above.

But that's ugly. Is there something better?

Comment: You have to specify full path to property from the root (`A` class in your case)

Comment: Yeah but like I said: if I want to specify the full path for all possible attributes I'd need to so much switch-case work to find out whether the attribute I got in the HTTP request is in A or B.

Comment: Well. You can create some kind of `Map<String, String>` with short alias of attribute and actual full path to that attribute. And before actual repository invocation you can replace sorting properties based on that Map

Comment: The work I have to do for both is quite similar, only difference is that a Map is O(1) in the best case. So there's no way to say Spring it should try to find the attribute by itself? That's so "out of character" for Spring.